# Process all messages in SQS, but stop if there is any error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a workflow where new files come into S3 continuously. These files are processed with lambda function (say, `F1`) and results are sent to a third-party database via Rest API. Sometimes, the third party API has errors and cannot receive the results. In that case, the results are sent to SQS queue.

There is another lambda function (say, `F2`) that runs every 6 hours which checks the SQS queue and attempts to send the messages to the third-party database. This worked fine because the maximum number of messages in the SQS never exceeded ~30 before.

Now, there's thousands of messages in the queue, and current approach has two major issues:

- One lambda cannot process all messages. This could potentially be fixed by increasing execution time.
- The lambda will attempt to process all messages in the queue even if the third party API still has issues.

The current solution I am pondering is to first attempt processing small number of messages in the queue with `F2`. If that is successful, trigger `F2` again (with `SNS` maybe).

What approach or AWS service would be appropriate for this situation?

Comment: These are design questions.  Obviously, the lambda should process smaller batches of messages, and should stop processing if the api is unavailable.  One of the benefits of using a queue, is that you should be able to support multiple workers, which could allow you to clear out the backlog.

Comment: It sounds like `F2` should start by checking whether the Third-Party API is operational. If it is not operational, then it should not attempt to process any messages. Schedule `F2` to trigger more often so it can keep checking if it can process the backlog. You could even trigger `F2` to run every 10 minutes -- if there is nothing in the queue, it will exit immediately. If a previous `F2` is already running, this will add more capacity and process messages in parallel, helping you empty the queue faster (assuming the 3rd-party API can handle the load).